# Integrate allure report with nunit test cases, have issues after adding [AllureNUnit] before [TestFixture]

Tags: c#, nunit, allure

I'm using Nunit.framework as my test case framework. Now I want to add allure report to my cases. I'm using allure.common and nunit.allure two packages.
The issue is: after adding [AllureNUnit] in the test case, all my testcase can't be loaded at all. Without adding [AllureNUnit], all the cases are running successful without error. But after adding it, the test data can't be loaded at all. Is there any conflict with any nunit packages?
Does anyone ever have this problem?

My package version is:  allure.common  V2.3.64.1, nunit.allure  V1.0.9. Because my nunit.framework is old version 3.11, so I use these two version of allure.

I just want to use allure report in my C# nunit test cases successful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can use allure report after adding app.config file, but its so strange, I don't want to use app.config for every project. Because that I need to add lots of app.config files for every different project. Is there any other simple way to get this? And the app.config content is just adding a nunit.framework package in the dependentAssembly part.